# 404 error after submitting form with ImageField on Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have created a Django admin using documentation tutorial. I have created a model `Author` and added 2 CharFields and one ImageField. If I want to add a new author, the page `admin/app/author/add/` works. I add everything and then, when I press Submit, I will be redirected on the same page `admin/app/author/add/`, but I will get the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    ******/admin/app/author/add/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view
Using the URLconf defined in ******.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
- admin/
- app/ [name='index']

The current path, app/author/add/, didn't match any of these.
```

The requested URL is `admin/app/author/add/`, but for some reason it searches for `app/author/add/`.

I tried to remove the ImageField and everything works fine, so I assume that the problem is ImageField.
I have installed Pillow.
I have done everything about static and media files deployment.

```
# app/models.py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/authors/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import *

admin.site.register(Quote)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Verb)
```

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you share your admin.py?

Comment: @IainShelvington Sure! I've edited the question

Comment: post URLs. Seems the issue is there, no?

Comment: "Raised by:" suggests that the 404 is being raised in the add_view. What storage backend are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington I am using mysql (mysqlclient 1.4.2 installed)

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' --- did u add this to settings?

Comment: @LucaDibattista I meant your media storage backend

Comment: @Jay yes, I added that line

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm sorry, I don't understand. I am trying to upload files on the same server of the code... do I need something to make everything work?

Comment: Have you set DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE to anything other than the default value?

Comment: Got it, I think. Add this to URLs  urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), path('', include('app.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: @Jay sorry, still not working. I think the issue is that it is searching for "/app/author/..." and not for "/admin/app/author/...", not that that url does not exist

Comment: @IainShelvington I haven't tried. Why should I? I'm just trying to store an image in a standard way. Or not? What could I try?

Comment: I agree, which I why I am thinking it is a mishap in your URLs -- Post the URLs of the app, not just the mysite URLs.